# C# Eventhandler with parameter control type from xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, eventhandler

I want to call onClick event and transfer Textbox object to the eventhandler from .xaml code.
is that posible?

i'll try to illustrate,

This is my Main.xaml.cs code:

```
<Button x:Name="VideoTargetBtn" Content="Browse..." HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="89"  Click="VideoTargetBtn_Click" Height="27" Margin="10,13,0,0"/>
<TextBox x:Name="videoTargetPathTxt" Height="27" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsReadOnly="True"  Margin="117,13,21,0"/>
```

And that's what I want to do:

```
private void VideoTargetBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e, TextBox currTextbox)
{
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    bool? fileIsSelected = saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();
    if (fileIsSelected == true)
    {
        currTextbox.Text = saveFileDialog.FileName;
    }
}
```

Comment: In general if you are using click handlers in WPF you are doing it wrong.

Comment: It's not my code, I tried to illustrate.

Comment: Does not matter if its your code, its wrong. You shouldn't be using click handlers in WPF period. Look up `MVVM` `ICommand` and `WPF`. This should be achieved with a `Command` with a `CommandParameter={Binding ElementName=videoTargetPathTxt, Path=Text}`.

Comment: @TalShaked I implemented a solution showing you the MVVM model below, it shows you some cool tricks, and allows the user to hit enter to invoke your method. I've kept out ViewModelLocator for simplicity so set the datacontext somewhere. IE for testing in codebehind or directly in xaml... or use a viewmodellocator =)

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is access the control from your code behind you can just reference it by name since you use the x:Name attribute on the control with a  value of videoTargetPathTxt.

Leave the event handler as normal and replace your code with

```
if (fileIsSelected == true)
{
    videoTargetPathTxt.Text = saveFileDialog.FileName;
}
```

Comment: every button with other textbox.

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't and you don't need to,

in the private VideoTargetBtn_Click handler just retrieve the textbox contents

```
videoTargetPathTxt.Text


private void VideoTargetBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();

    bool? fileIsSelected = saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();

    if (fileIsSelected == true)
    {
        videoTargetPathTxt.Text = saveFileDialog.FileName;
    }
}
```